# I have the problem with adding datasource to the subreport of my Jasper Report in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource

In main datasource I have a field "List someDto". And I need to add this field to subreport datasource. Maybe I can use some expression, that will return JRDataSource type?

```
report.addDetail(subreport(report()
                .addDetail(text(field("text", String.class)))
                .addDetail(image(fieldExpression("image")))
                .setDataSource(----*here i need to add field from main datasource*----)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, I just use subDatasourceBeanCollection and replace .setDataSource from the report().setDataSource to subreport(...).setDataSource():

`report.addDetail(subreport(report()
                .addDetail(text(field("text", String.class)))
                .addDetail(image(fieldExpression("image"))))
                .setDataSource(subDatasourceBeanCollection("*here my field from main datasource")));`